# iOS Autolayout Programmatically constraints using VFL

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, ios-autolayout, visual-format-language

I wants to make a close button like this,

[image]

- I tried to pin button, but the button was shrinked or disappeared
  Here was code,

**Shrinked**

```
[constraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[btnClose(==10)]-|"
                                                                         options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY
                                                                         metrics:nil
                                                                           views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(btnClose)]];
```

**Disappeared with error**

```
[constraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[btnClose(==-10)]-|"
                                                                         options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY
                                                                         metrics:nil
                                                                           views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(btnClose)]];
```

- The blue view is also set using autolayout and it's working fine in all screens.

What constraints should I apply to make close button support in all devices like shown in image.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should provide both horizontal and vertical constraints (if 10 and 0 are spaces to top and right):

```
[constraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[btnClose]-0-|"
                                                                         options:0
                                                                         metrics:nil
                                                                           views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(btnClose)]];

[constraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-10-[btnClose]"
                                                                         options:0
                                                                         metrics:nil
                                                                           views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(btnClose)]];
```

You don't need to specify dimensions of button - they will be inferred from content, in your case image size